# NGRX Store - data changes on server not applied to state

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I've been working with `NGRX` for awhile, and finally uncovered an issue that has been plaguing me for awhile.

In essence: properties that I alter on the server, and then are returned by the service in the ngrx effect are not shown as a difference as a difference when updating the store, and therefore the store is not updated for those changes. In my example below I changed `targetDepth` in the front end. You'll see in the hardcoding i did to prove my thesis I would expect the store to update both the `targetDepth` and the `targetWidth`.

[image: Redux State]
I hard coded a change in the method,

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri]int key, [FromBody] PlanDTO expPlan)
{
    //DO a bunch of stuff

    //Save & error handling

    var result = GetPlan(key);
    result.FirstOrDefault().TargetWidth++;  //Dummy code for testing, not real logic
    return new ObjectResult(result);   //Return saved value
}
```

My effect is here:

```
    @Effect()
    editPlan$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .pipe(ofType<Edit>(PlanActionTypes.Edit),
            switchMap(action => this.planService.editPlan(action.payload)),
            map((plan: any) => {

             // var changes = {...plan}  //--This line changes the behavior entirely

                return new EditSuccess({ id: plan.id, changes: plan});
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                this.toastr.error(`An error has occurred. Please reload the page before making any other changes.`);
                console.error(err);
                return of(new EditFail(err));
            })
        );
```

I can toggle to a new problem by adding `var changes = {...plan}` and passing that. Then the store is only updated with values from the server but somehow skips the change made in the UI. To say it another way if i do this, `targetWidth` is updated but not `targetDepth`. Id like both, but I am not sure what I'm missing. Thanks.

**Edit**: Im willing to share more bits, but didn't want to provide extraneous information

**Edit2** Relevant reducer

```
 export function reducer(
  state = fromState.initialState,
  action: PlanActionsUnion
): State {
  switch (action.type) {
       case PlanActionTypes.EditSuccess: {
          return adapter.updateOne(action.payload, state);
        }
    }
```

**Edit3** Accidental behavior fix. I dont understand why,.

Changing the service to enumerate results from IQueryable beforehand seems to fix the behavior.

```
    var result = GetPlan(key);
    var resultFirst =  result.FirstOrDefault();
    var resultFirst.targetWidth++;
    return new ObjectResult(resultFirst);   //Return saved value
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what your problem is .. but if is that the state is not updating on `EditSucess` action maybe the problem is in the reducer .. post the code of the reducer?

Comment: I'll post the reducer. The state is updating, just not everything.

I Update TargetDepth on my front end. Save it to my database via a patch method,and update another calculated field in the patch method. On the return TargetDepth is updated in the store, the calculated field is not. Alternatively I can enable the changes = {...plan} line, and then the calculated field is updated in the store, but TargetDepth is not.

Comment: @cabesuon - Up until this point, I never wanted to update more data, I had always just assumed that what we going to the store was the result in the patch method I posted. A feature request required me to calculate another field on the back end, and show both changes in the UI, which uncovered that the store wasnt actually updating based on the server, but the changeset I was posting to the server instead. up till now those things have been 1:1

Comment: GetPlan(key) is being invoked server side, On the server i'm updating a property (targetWidth)  and it does not show that change in the store. it only shows the change in targetDepth.

Comment: I see, last question, have you check that the respond from the server is the expected?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed the response is exactly what I want

Comment: How is `Plan` defined? .. A I am asking because in the reducer you are passing `{id:number, changes: Plan}` to `updateOne`, but shouldn't be just `Plan`

Comment: @cabesuon - id is on plan, and you are right, but that is how NGRX Update<Entity> is defined:

Comment: If it is working .. To be sure, have you check the payload in the reducer just before the update?, it has both values changed?

Comment: @cabesuon yes, it did, though ive made a more interesting discovery, see edit.

Comment: So, you solve it then?

Comment: Well by accident and I dont understand why that solved it.